# Use a table in Where clause

Tags: sql, ios, sqlite

My array contains some elements:

```
(
    "element 1",
    "element 2",
    "element 3"
)
```

I need to query the database, and fetch for every single element stored in the array above in the database:

```
 select * from table1 where type=?
```

I got the idea of a for loop, for the array, and the select query will be repeated depending on the size of the array, which is not so useful.

Any thoughts, thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`IN` operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op):

```
select * from table1 where type in ('element1', 'element2');
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, but in my case `'element1', 'element2'` are stored in a `NSMutableArray`, so how can i convert the `NSMutable` array into a String like so ?

Comment: You should be using a parameterized query: `select * from table where type in (?, ?)` then [bind them to your values](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like

```
    select * from table1 where type in ('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
```

?